# angular oauth2 oidc - Refresh token is not being set

Tags: angular-oauth2-oidc

Hello I am using the following configuration for angular `oauth2-oidc`

```js
function configure(authService: OAuthService){
 authService.configure({
 requireHttps: false,
 responseType: 'code token' ,
 oidc: false , 
 skipIssuerCheck: true , 
 strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
issuer : 'my-issuer',
redirectUrl: 'localhost:4200/#/check',
loginUrl: 'my-url',
clientId : 'some-id',
scope: 'my-scope offline_access'
 }
 )
}
```

After doing `authService.initLoginFlow()` and get redirected to my application  event though i can see the refresh_token in the url , it is never set in the session storage. Any Ideas what other I can check?

I am using angular 14 and `angular-oauth2-oidc` : 14.0.1